# The einbein in the action of a relativistic massive point particles

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, action, point-particles

The action of a relativistic massive point particle moving in space-time is

\begin{equation}
S=-m\int d\tau \sqrt{g _{\nu \rho}\frac{dx^{\nu}}{d\tau}\frac{dx^{\rho}}{d\tau}}\tag{1}
\label{eq1}
\end{equation}

[with Minkowski sign convention $(+,-,-,-)$]. Now this action has two problems; first, because of the square root, it would be very difficult to quantize it. Second, such action won't yield the correct dynamics for a massless particle $(m = 0 \rightarrow S = 0)$. People then replace $(Eq.\ref{eq1})$ with the following action;

\begin{equation}
S=\frac{1}{2}\int d\tau(e^{-1}\dot{X}^{2}-em^{2}).
\tag{2}
\label{eq2}
\end{equation}

I understand how this action will eventually generate the correct dynamics of the massless particle; by varying this action and choosing the gauge $e = 1$, we can get the equation of motion of the particle (Einstein relation);
\begin{equation} 
\dot{x} + m^2 = 0 \quad \Rightarrow(m = 0)\Rightarrow \quad p^2 = 0.
\end{equation}
I found this [post](https://www.ellipsix.net/blog/2010/08/the-origin-of-the-einbein.html) from 2010, he provides a great explanation for how to come up with $(Eq.\ref{eq2})$, and resolving the problems with our initial guess for the action.

- Why does such a method work? how does one fix a troubled action?
- Where can I learn more about this method?

Comment: That's too bad, but where's the question here?

Comment: How can you come up with the action that has the einbein field? I know this sounds trivial I didn't study general relativity yet .

Comment: Do you get what I'm asking here ?

Comment: No, not really. Actions aren't derived, they're postulated (*motivated* by some kind of symmetry, but essentially, writing down an action is an educated guess that *defines* the theory).

Comment: Yes . I know that they aren't derived. The problem is that I can't come up with that guess myself  before reading the postulated action from the book

Answer (score 5):

The story is the following. We start with the simplest Poincare-invariant action that does not depend on the parametrization
$$ S=-m\int dl=-m\int\sqrt{-ds^2}$$
here $ds^2$ is the interval. We can rewrite it as
$$S=-m\int\sqrt{dX^\mu dX^\nu \eta_{\mu\nu}}$$
here $\eta_{\mu\nu}$ is the Minkowski metric. Now if we suppose that $X^\mu$ depend only on $\tau$ we get $dX^\mu=\dot{X}^\mu d\tau$
$$ S=-m\int d\tau (-\dot{X}^\mu\dot{X}_\mu)^{1/2}.$$

Now we note (we guess and then check) that the above action is equivalent to the following
$$ S'=\frac{1}{2}\int d\tau(\eta^{-1}\dot{X}^\mu\dot{X}_\mu-\eta m^2).$$ And indeed the equation of motion for $\eta$ (which is obtained from $\displaystyle{\frac{\delta S}{\delta \eta}=0}$) is
$$\eta^2=-\frac{\dot{X}^\mu\dot{X}_\mu}{m^2}.$$ Now if you substitute this expression into $S'$ you get the original action $S$.