# General construction of equations of motion for free particles

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, special-relativity, classical-mechanics, symmetry, group-theory

I've got a question regarding the different Symmetrie-Lie-Groups of Newtonian Mechanics and special realtivity. Is there a canonical way to obtain the equations of motion for a free particle only by the symmetrie-group?

I just found that according to J.M. Souriau the Lie-Group should act transitively so there is no further structure.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/23098/2451 and links there.

Answer (score 1):

There is, in a sense, a way to 'guide' oneself to the equations of motion based on the symmetries. The form of mechanics most suitable for this purpose is [Hamilton's principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamilton%27s_principle) - the system takes a path for which the action has a stationary value for variations with fixed endpoints:
$$\delta S=0$$

$S$ is generally expressed as (under some parametrization of paths with parameter $t$):
$$S = \int_{path} L(x, \dot{x})dt$$

Leading to the equations of motion:
$$\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}} = \frac{\partial L}{\partial x}$$

Now, in general, one expects the action respect the symmetries of the problem. Consider the following examples:

**Newtonian mechanics**

Here, we have particles where the position is given as a function of time: $x(t)$. Due to the translation and rotation invariance respectively, we require that the action $S$ does not depend on any preferred position or direction. The form we effectively have is then $L = L(|\dot{x}|)$.
We further require it to respect Galilean symmetry. For this, we require that $\delta S$ is invariant under $\dot{x} \rightarrow \dot{x}+u$ for constant $u$. This is possible when $L = \frac{1}{2}m\dot{x}^2$, so that under this transformation
$$S = \int\frac{1}{2}m\dot{x}^2dt \rightarrow \int\frac{1}{2}m\dot{x}^2dt + \int mu\ dx + \int\frac{1}{2}mu^2dt$$
The last two terms are only functions of the endpoint of the path, and therefore their variation vanishes i.e. $\delta\int dx = \delta\int dt = 0$. This leads to the equation of motion:
$$m\ddot{x} = 0$$
or
$$\ddot{x} = 0$$

This is precisely the equation of motion one would obtain for a free particle according to Newton's second law.
(Note: Mechanics is presented this way, for example, in *[Landau and Lifshitz, Mechanics](http://books.google.co.in/books/about/Mechanics.html?id=e-xASAehg1sC&redir_esc=y)*).

**Special Relativity**

Here, we require that the action is invariant under Lorentz transformations, in addition to being translation invariant.
Thus, for the action, we choose the integral over paths of the spacetime interval itself:
$$S = m\int \sqrt{\eta_{\mu\nu} dx^{\mu} dx^{\nu}}$$

Setting $\delta S=0$ leads to the geodesic equation of motion for a free particle i.e. the motion is a straight line in spacetime.

I'm not sure if this qualifies as a 'canonical' way; it is more like making educated guesses.

Comment: The problem occuring for me here, is that the construction is really a guess guided by historical developments.
I'm searching for a way to do the construction for a mostly arbitrary symmetry group or a construction which doesn't use the foliation of spacetime in the Galilean case as the given one and thereby might lead to a generalisation not diretly using the spevial symmetry group.

Comment: There is certainly a difference between the two constructions presented here: one is explicitly invariant under its symmetry transformations, the other isn't. While it is possible to actually construct a Galilean invariant action (http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/15315/77679), it requires introducing auxiliary variables. Once again, we can have a different Lorentz invariant action with auxiliary variables, generally used to treat the massless case (http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/167296/77679). But they both look different; if there is a general method, it is, at least, hidden.